# Display Text On Click Inside Different DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three divs. One div has a Twitter icon, one div has a LinkedIn icon and the last div is where I want text to display `onclick`.

I would like to be able to click on the Twitter icon and have text display in that third div. Then if I click on the LinkedIn icon, the text will change and display specific text for LinkedIn. These are not feeds. Right now I can click on the Twitter icon and the text will display but it displays under the icon and I need it to display in the third div that says "Posts Go Here."

The main page is .php.

Code for divs is:

```
<div class="capamb-row-padding">
    <div class="capamb-third">
      <p><label for="toggle">
      <img src="/images/capambassador/capamb-twitter-icon.png" width="75" height="75" />
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
      <span>your text here</span>
    </div>

   <div class="capamb-third">
       <p><img src="/images/capambassador/capamb-linkedin-icon.png" width="75" height="75" /></p>
    </div>

    <div class="capamb-third">
        <h2>Tweets</h2>
        <p>Posts Go Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show the code used to display the text ? It would help to answer accurately.

Comment: When you click on icon/image the resultant text will be static or it will keep changes ?

Comment: Forgot to include my CSS:

#toggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

span{
    display: none;
}

#toggle:checked + span{
    display: block;
 
}

img{
    cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: The text will change week to week but we will manually go in and change it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $('img[alt="twitter"]').click(function() {
    $('div.capamb-third:nth-child(3) h2').text('Tweets');
    $('div.capamb-third:nth-child(3) p').text('Twitter Posts Go Here');
  });
  $('img[alt="linkedin"]').click(function() {
    $('div.capamb-third:nth-child(3) h2').text('Posts');
    $('div.capamb-third:nth-child(3) p').text('LinkedIn Posts Go Here');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="capamb-row-padding">
  <div class="capamb-third">
    <p>
      <label for="toggle">
        <img src="/images/capambassador/capamb-twitter-icon.png" width="75" height="75" alt="twitter" />
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
      <span>your text here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="capamb-third">
    <p>
      <img src="/images/capambassador/capamb-linkedin-icon.png" width="75" height="75" alt="linkedin" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="capamb-third">
    <h2>Tweets</h2>
    <p>Posts Go Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. Where should I place:


    '$(function() {
    $('img[alt="twitter"]').click(function() {
    $('div.capamb-third:nth-child(3) h2').text('Tweets');
    $('div.capamb-third:nth-child(3) p').text('Twitter Posts Go Here');
  });
  $('img[alt="linkedin"]').click(function() {
    $('div.capamb-third:nth-child(3) h2').text('Posts');
    $('div.capamb-third:nth-child(3) p').text('LinkedIn Posts Go Here');
  });
});'

Comment: In your HTML `<head>` section, create a tag `<script type="text/javascript"> Paste the above code here </script>`

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

the trigger:

```
<img id="trigger" src="/images/capambassador/capamb-twitter-icon.png" width="75" height="75" />
```

the target:

```
<p id="hidden-text">Posts Go Here</p>
```

the js:

```
var trigger = document.getElementById('toggle'),
    hidden = document.getElementById('hidden-text');

trigger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    hidden.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The following is a javascript solution to this:

First of all, please provie an iD to each of the div's. Let's say `first, second and third`.

Now you can add an `onclick= "msg(first.value)"` to the first div and `onclick= "msg(second.value)"` to second div.

The definition of msg(a):
`function msg(a){
third.innerHTML+=a;}`

HoPe this helps!

Answer (score -1):

This script may help you. Third div is at the bottom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>your title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <div class="capamb-row-padding">
  <div class="capamb-third" id='one'>
    <p>
      <label for="toggle">
        <img src="https://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_blue.png" width="75" height="75" />
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
      <span>your text here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="capamb-third" id='two'>
    <p>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/LinkedIn_logo_initials.png/768px-LinkedIn_logo_initials.png" width="75" height="75" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="capamb-third" id='three'>
   
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$("#one").click(function(){
    $("#three").html("<h2>Tweets</h2><br><p>Tweets go here</p>");
});
$("#two").click(function(){
    $("#three").html("<h2>Linkedin</h2><br><p>Posts Go Here</p>");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Since this is a PHP document, where would I place the jquery?

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out.

Comment: You can use jquery in php document also.